# Send serialized JSON in restTemplate postForObject

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Here is the deal.

I have a *postForObject* to sent. In that *postForObject*, i must send **2** objects:

- A **JSON** OBJECT WITH NAME **"DATA"** (e.g:
  data={"client":"name","id":"3"})
- A **STRING** WITH NAME **"SESSION_TOKEN"** (e.g: session_token="abc")

I've tried so many ways do this but i've always receive a **400 (BAD REQUEST)** from server even though the same way being used with **CURL** in **PHP**. *(I've checked the arguments that the curl php script sends and are exactly the two i described above)*

So, here are my question:

1. How can i manage/create these **2** arguments **(JSON being serialized)** and sent via *postForObject*? Can someone explain **step by step** this process? *(So i can get a good understanding about the issue since i'm new to Java/Spring)*

**P.S.:** *I've already did multiple **getForObject** functions that worked fine. I really just need the way **HOW** can i pass these arguments (1 Json **serialized** and 1 String) with **postForObject**.*

**--------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE** *(Send Post Arguments are now working)*

I've success sending POST data via **postForObject**

Just create the RestTemplate like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
HttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverternew = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
```

and the attributes must be created with **MultiValueMap** like this:

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("session_token",session_token);
```

then, to finish, sent the **postForObject** like this:

```
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

    String result = restTemplate.postForObject(API_URL + "company/6788/appointment/", map, String.class);
```

**THE QUESTION NOW IS:**

Which is the best way to serialize a **JSON EXACTLY**  like this:

```
{"client_email":"kalvinmoraes@gmail.com","client_name":"Alexandre Moraes"}
```

to

```
%7B%22client_email%22%3A%22kalvinmoraes%40gmail.com%22%2C%22client_name%22%3A%22Alexandre%20Moraes%22%7D
```

Comment: The `data=` part of it is not json. In the most basic situation, you can serialize it yourself. Or, you can use libraries like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to serialize java objects.

Comment: Google for the JSON.org home page.  (And bookmark it.)  At the bottom are listed a dozen or so different packages for serializing/deserializing JSON in Java.  Pick one you like.

Comment: @HotLicks is bookmarking necessary?

Comment: @standalone - If you're planning to do a lot of JSON stuff.